# Prevent skip in docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` for a Django web app with a backend. It looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: # special image
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      PASSWORD: "*********"

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

When I run `sudo docker-compose build`, the first line of output says

```
db uses an image, skipping. 
Building web.
```

I need the `db` image to be built before `web`.

How can I make the `db` image get built first?

Comment: Assuming you mean 'run' for the DB image, rather than 'build'? How are you expecting the behavior here to be different than what's happening?

Comment: @JHarris Yes, 'run' rather than 'build'. The web build requires the `db` be up and running in order for it to complete. That's why I need `db` to be run first.

Comment: Generally agree with blackrobot's answer. This seems like bad design. Can't you initialise the DB connection / dependency on run, rather than build? Makes the whole thing a bit more robust.

Comment: The `depends_on` should do what you are describing. Are you experiencing a different outcome or error? Does the "special image" function as expected? If so, this should work -- the `web` service will be built on `docker-compose build`, the `db` image will create and run the `db` service, then the `web` service will run from the just built `web` image. It won't check anything other than the `db` container is running, so if you need to verify any status more specifically than that, it's something you'll have to manage. The Compose docs go in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start your `db` container in [Detached mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) before building `web`:

```bash
$ docker-compose up -d db
$ docker-compose build web
```

Though, this [seems like an anti-pattern](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/containers-should-be-ephemeral). I would recommended that you keep the build process for `web` as generic as possible, and instead use environment variables or [`command` arguments](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/command) to accomplish this.

For instance, if you need to pass the same configuration values to both `web` and `db`, you could accomplish this using [an `env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/env-file):

```
# db_credentials.env
USER="django"
PASSWORD="********"
DATABASE="django_db"
```

And in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    # ...
    env_file: db_credentials.env

  web:
    # ...
    env_file: db_credentials.env
```